# Unity Trail for Eyes 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, particles, trail-renderer

i want to make some kind of an Eye Tail effect for this charakter:
[image]

I found the Unity Trail Renderer effect but the start of the Trial is perpendicular to the dragged/moved direction:

[image]

Can i make the start of the Trail look like the eye block of the charakter? So that if he move left or right, the Trail is only as width as the Eyes height and if the moves up or down, the Trail is correspondingly width. Or is there a better method for making a cool Eye Tail effect?